# Simple Code works in Debug, not in Release

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, objective-c-category

So this isn't making sense at all.  I have an extension method to `NSMutableArray` to move an item from one index to another.  It's a fairly simple method and it works flawlessly when I compile my app in Debug Configuration.  However, if I compile the app in Release Configuration, it crashes if I move from an item down (from index > to index).  The crash isn't a an index out of bounds error.  My local variable are being messed up and I have no idea why.  Here's the entire method:

```
- (void)    moveObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)fromIndex toIndex:(NSUInteger)toIndex{
    if (fromIndex == toIndex) return; 
    if (fromIndex >= self.count) return; 
    if (toIndex >= self.count) toIndex = self.count - 1; //toIndex too large, assume a move to end
    id movingObject = [self objectAtIndex:fromIndex];

    if (fromIndex < toIndex){
        for (int i = fromIndex; i <= toIndex; i++){
            [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:(i == toIndex) ? movingObject : [self objectAtIndex:i + 1]];
        }
    } else {
        //The problem occurs in this block (though the crash doesn't always occur here)
        id cObject;
        id prevObject;
        for (int i = toIndex; i <= fromIndex; i++){
            //usually on the last loop, my "prevObject" become 'messed up' after the following line:
            cObject = [self objectAtIndex:i];
            [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:(i == toIndex) ? movingObject : prevObject];
            prevObject = cObject;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't step through the code since it's a release build, but I've NSLogged the variables at each step through the loop.  Usually, on the last loop the `prevObject` var is assigned some random variable when `cObject = [self objectAtIndex:i];` completes.  Sometimes it's set to `nil` but often it's some other random variable in my code.  If it's `nil` the code crashes when I try to replace the object in the array.  Otherwise, it crashes later on when I try to access the array and receive back the wrong object.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?  I mean, the problem is occurring in 4 lines of code, which I've been over a hundred times.

Comment: Wild guess: it looks like a pointer thing. how about copying the [self objectAtIndex:i] instead  of assigning?

Comment: It's a generic routine.  I can't assume any object in the array is copy-able.  In fact, I know that in many cases the object can't be copied.

Comment: I would guess that in debug mode you have some logic that's compiled out in release mode.  The logic may actually be initializing something that needs initializing, or, more subtly, the logic may (by virtue of what it references) be causing ARC to "retain" a value that ARC releases in release mode.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, that makes sense.  ARC isn't perfect yet and I suppose there will be some edge cases where release build optimizations may interfere with ARC.  Usually, at the end of a 3-hour bug chasing session I expect to have a "Oh, I get it!" moment, not a "WTF? why-did-that-work" head-scratching moment.  But oh well, who ever said programming was logical?

Comment: It's not that it "interferes" with ARC, or that ARC is "imperfect" (though I certainly wouldn't want either side of that debate).  Rather you may be missing a `strong` or some such, but it works because ARC sees another reference that makes the object persist.  If that other reference disappears (compiled out) then the object goes poof.

Comment: lol..yeah I wouldn't want to debate "imperfect" ARC, but it might be fun to watch.  You may be right but I can't see how my code would create a situation where ARC would release the object.  They're all local in scope (which is strong by default) and we're talking about a very tight for-loop with 3-lines of codes in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just as the problem/crash made no sense, so also the fix doesn't make any sense at all.  I had started to just randomly change up the code to see if anything would work.  Moving the line: `prevObject = cObject` to the very beginning of the loop fixed the problem.  Doing this didn't change the logic at all... Nada... shouldn't have made a difference.  And yet, it did.  Whoever said programming is logical?  Here's the code that works:

```
- (void)    moveObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)fromIndex toIndex:(NSUInteger)toIndex{
    if (fromIndex == toIndex) return; 
    if (fromIndex >= self.count) return; 
    if (toIndex >= self.count) toIndex = self.count - 1; //toIndex too large, assume a move to end
    id movingObject = [self objectAtIndex:fromIndex];

    if (fromIndex < toIndex){
        for (int i = fromIndex; i <= toIndex; i++){
            [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:(i == toIndex) ? movingObject : [self objectAtIndex:i + 1]];
        }
    } else {
        id cObject = nil;
        id prevObject;
        for (int i = toIndex; i <= fromIndex; i++){
            prevObject = cObject;
            cObject = [self objectAtIndex:i];
            [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:(i == toIndex) ? movingObject : prevObject];
        }
    }
}
```

So, anybody want to chime in as to what's going on?

Comment: local vars dont init to nil (ivars do) prevObject = cObject says randomJunk = randomJunk on the first entry. Looks like you do the same thing in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that earlier.  But it doesn't make a difference.  The logic will never use a garbage variable.  `cObject` is used only after it's set to an object from the array and `prevObject` isn't used until after the first loop (when it's set to the previous cObject).  I did try setting everything to `nil` as one of my first attempts.  I had just copied the code over before I made that change.

Comment: [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:(i == toIndex) ? movingObject : prevObject]; could potentially use uninit'd junk as prevObject isnt  assigned before this point.

Comment: The initial conditions of the for loop sets `int i = toIndex;`, which means the first loop will always resolve the ternary condition to `movingObject`.  Logically it's impossible, though I understand the need for redundancy in your logic, which is why I modified my answer to set `cObject = nil;`.